# Using MAX to find the lastest time given other attribtues

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Here's an example of the data set layout:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b537554bb5e9dbde4f6c662fc302db5f

I want to write a select query to get the last product that arrived for each Vendor, by date.

Sample data:

```
Line | date                    | Vendor             | Product_Name | Arrival_Time
---: | :---------------------- | :----------------- | :----------- | :-----------
   1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Fruits Fruit Fuits | Bananas      | 14:30:00    
   2 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Fruits Fruit Fuits | Apples       | 13:30:00    
   3 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Fruits Fruit Fuits | Oranges      | 08:30:00    
   4 | 2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 | Fruits Fruit Fuits | Apples       | 15:30:00    
   5 | 2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 | Fruits Fruit Fuits | Oranges      | 12:30:00    
   6 | 2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 | Fruits Fruit Fuits | Bananas      | 04:30:00    
   7 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Fruits & More      | Bananas      | 21:30:00    
   8 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Fruits & More      | Apples       | 00:30:00    
   9 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Fruits & More      | Oranges      | 05:30:00    
  10 | 2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 | Fruits & More      | Apples       | 23:30:00    
  11 | 2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 | Fruits & More      | Oranges      | 15:30:00    
  12 | 2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 | Fruits & More      | Bananas      | 01:30:00
```

Desired results:

```
Line | date                    | Vendor             | Product_Name | Arrival_Time
---: | :---------------------- | :----------------- | :----------- | :-----------
   1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Fruits Fruit Fuits | Bananas      | 14:30:00    
   4 | 2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 | Fruits Fruit Fuits | Apples       | 15:30:00    
   7 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Fruits & More      | Bananas      | 21:30:00    
  10 | 2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 | Fruits & More      | Apples       | 23:30:00
```

So, in the example provided, I would want the query to return Line 1 (14:30 is the latest time on 9/1 for Fruits Fruits Fruits), Line 7 (21:30 is the latest time for Fruits & More on 9/1, Line 4 (15:30 is the latest time on 9/1 for Fruits Fruits Fruits), etc.

I think I'm missing a subquery or maybe I need to fiddle with my group by.

Comment: Providing a db fiddle is very nice. However questions should stand by themselves. I copied the data and results to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from availability a
where a.arrival_time = (
    select max(a1.arrival_time)
    from availability a1
    where a1.vendor = a.vendor 
        and a1.date >= convert(date, a.date) 
        and a1.date < dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, a.date))
);
```

The conditions on the dates could be expressed more simply as `convert(date, a.date) = convert(date, a1.date)`, but the above expressions are likely to be more efficient, especially with an index on `(vendor, date, arrival_time)`.

Another typical approach is window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select a.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by a.vendor, convert(date, a.date) order by a.arrival_time desc) rn
    from availability a
) a
where rn = 1
```

Comment: thank you so much!  This is exactly what i wanted.  I haven't used window functions before, but maybe this is a good time to learn.  Thanks for that example too!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
select * from 
(
    select Line
         , date
         , vendor
         , product_name
         , arrival_time
         , row_number() over (partition by vendor, date order by arrival_time desc) num  
    from availability 
) data
where num = 1
order by Line
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to use the `WITH TIES` clause

**Example**

```
SELECT top 1 with ties * 
FROM  availability
order by row_number() over (partition by date,vendor order by arrival_time desc)
```

Returns

```
Line    date                    Vendor              Product_Name    Arrival_Time
7       2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 Fruits & More       Bananas         21:30:00
1       2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 Fruits Fruit Fuits  Bananas         14:30:00
10      2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 Fruits & More       Apples          23:30:00
4       2020-09-02 00:00:00.000 Fruits Fruit Fuits  Apples          15:30:00
```

Comment: woah, this is some crazy magic!  Never even heard of that one. I'll have to try that out.